# Is there a way to get status message and images from https://graph.facebook.com/me./locations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

https://graph.facebook.com/me/locations returns all the posts a user is in with a location. However it does not include the message text or images as me/posts does. Is there a way to get this info in me/locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using me/posts and looking for the ones with locations. It returns all the images and messages.

Answer (score 1):

How about using FQL [`location_post`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/) table?

Not sure what exactly you want to pull, but this is how you pull statuses with locations:

```
SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT id FROM location_post WHERE author_uid=me() OR USER_ID IN tagged_uids)
```

Change `USER_ID` to yours.